# How to create a simple facade over mongo with dart?

Tags: mongodb, dart

I would like to have a nice and simple layer over a mongodb instance using dart, and I cannot manage to do it :

**Given a mongodb instance "test-mongo-layer" :**

mongo shell :

use test-mongo-layer switched to db test-mongo-layer
db.users.find() 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("524b1bf8fbfe21c9c4cdb772"), "name" : "Toto", "login" : "toto" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("524b1bf8fbfe21c9c4cdb772"), "name" : "Titi", "login" : "titi" }

**And a model.dart source file :**

```dart
class User {
  String name;
  String login;

  User(this.name, this.login)

  User.fromJson(Map map) {
    name  = map['name'];
    login = map['login'];
  }
}
```

**And a persistence.dart source file :**

```dart
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';
import '../lib/model.dart';

class PersistenceLayer{

  Db _mongodb;

  PersistenceLayer(this._mongodb)

  List<User> getUsers() {

    List<User> users = new List();

    _mongodb.open().then((o){

      return __mongodb.collection('users').find().forEach((jsonUser){
        User user = new User.fromJson(jsonUser);
        users.add(user);  
      });

    }).then((jsonUsers){

      _mongodb.close();

    });

    return users;
  }

}
```

**When I launch the following test :**

```dart
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import '../lib/model.dart' ;
import '../lib/persistence.dart' ;
main() {

  Db db = new Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1/test-mongo-layer");

  test('Test get users', () {

      PersistenceLayer persistence = new PersistenceLayer(db);
      var users = persistence.getUsers();
      expect(users.length, 2);
  }

}
```

**Then a got an exception :**

Uncaught Error: Expected: <2>
  Actual: <0><

This is quite simple but it's not working, i must mess with the Future because the code is not even executed when I execute it on debug...

**SOLUTION** : thanks to Alexandre

persistence.dart source file :

```dart
  Future<List<User>> getUsers() {
    List<User> users = new List();
    return _mongodb.open()
                .then((_){
                    return _mongodb.collection('users').find().forEach((jsonUser){
                       User user = new User.fromJson(jsonUser);
                       users.add(user);
                       });
                })
               .then((_) {
                    return users;
                })
                .whenComplete((){
                    _mongodb.close();
                });
   }
```

test :

```dart
test('Test get users', () {
      PersistenceLayer persitence = new MongoPersistence(db);
      Future<List<User>> usersFuture = persistence.getUsers();
      usersFuture.then((users) => expect(users.length, 2)   );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing sync and async code in your `getUsers`. The filling of `users` is done after that `getUsers()` is returned. That's why `users` is empty.

To better understand `Future` and async code you can have a look at [The Event Loop and Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/).

A working version of `getUsers()` should look like the following (not tested) :

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';
import '../lib/model.dart';

class PersistenceLayer{
  Db _mongodb;

  PersistenceLayer(this._mongodb)

  Future<List<User>> getUsers() {
    List<User> users = new List();
    return _mongodb.open().then((_){
      _mongodb.collection('users').find().forEach((jsonUser){
        User user = new User.fromJson(jsonUser);
        users.add(user);
      });
    }).whenComplete((_){
      _mongodb.close();
    }).then((_) => users);
  }
}
```

Basically you return the complete `Future` chain and in the last `then` you return `users`.

Comment: So I cannot make getUsers() synchronous as long as it's using mongo_dart library that provide asynchronous functions ?

Comment: Exact ! Asynchronous is contagious. Once you have one `Future` in a function you almost always have to make the function return a `Future`.